# Project is Using Dagger, but Library Project is using Guice. Can I use both?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-library, roboguice, dagger

So I have a project where I do dependency injection with Dagger, but I want to use a library project that uses RoboGuice.

When I try to run it, I get the following error when entering the library project:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{PROJECT.debug/LIBRARY.Activity}: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
    1) Could not find a suitable constructor in PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
            at PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator.class(Unknown Source)
    while locating PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator
    for field at PROJECT.ProjectApplication._advertistingTrackingAggregator(Unknown Source)
            at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:141)
    1 error
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)

....
   Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:
    1) Could not find a suitable constructor in PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
            at PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator.class(Unknown Source)
    while locating PROJECT.AdvertisingTrackingAggregator
    for field at PROJECT.ProjectApplication._advertistingTrackingAggregator(Unknown Source)
            at roboguice.config.DefaultRoboModule.configure(DefaultRoboModule.java:141)
    1 error
            at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:83)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:94)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:139)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.getBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:59)
            at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:149)
            at com.github.rtyley.android.sherlock.roboguice.activity.RoboSherlockFragmentActivity.onCreate(RoboSherlockFragmentActivity.java:31)
            at LIBRARY.ui.activity.AbstractLibraryActivity.onCreate(AbstractLibraryActivity.java:149)
            at LIBRARY.ui.activity.LibraryLandingActivity.onCreate(LibraryLandingActivity.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
            ... 10 more
```

Does the Library need to configure itself with Module to avoid looking for @Inject annotations that I use in my project via Dagger?

How do I get past the Guice/Dagger fight?

Comment: First, there's no fight - Dagger and Guice are both google-sponsored projects.

Comment: Second - I'm a little confused - what parts of the graph are you configuring with roboguice, and what parts with dagger.  Dagger should not be starting up guice so I'm confused as to what your program's flow is that would result in this.

Comment: Basically, I have an basic Android Application that is using Dagger to inject dependencies, e.g. the AdvertisingTrackingAggregator in the ProjectApplication context.

This Application is making use of a Library that provides UI via Activities. The Library project is using Guice for view/dependency injection in its Activity contexts. It seems when one of these Activities starts, the DefaultRoboModule is picking up the @Inject tags in the Application context that should be configured with Dagger, and throwing exceptions because of how those dependency classes are structured.

Comment: Is the library project just improperly configured and not making proper use of modules?